# How to implement get_tensor_by_name and predict in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow.js

I want to use [Faster rcnn inception v2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yNIC9TD1MWzJyI3ewnJCmM1bmTAYC_1E/view?usp=sharing) to do object detection in tensorflow.js. But i can't find some method in tfjs like get_tensor_by_name and session run for prediction.

In tensorflow (python), the [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OiQlfijNkTr6jQEpZafZmTjN1DTLsY7S/view?usp=sharing) as the following:

**Define input and output node:**

```
# Definite input Tensors for detection_graph
self.image_tensor = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Definite output Tensors for detection_graph
self.detection_boxes = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
self.detection_scores = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
self.detection_classes = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
self.num_detections = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
```

**Predict:**

```
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = self.sess.run(
            [self.detection_boxes, self.detection_scores, self.detection_classes, self.num_detections],
            feed_dict={self.image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
```

Do anyone know how to implement those two part of code in tfjs?

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `session.run` function in tensorflow.Js as there is in Python. In python, you start defining a graph and in the `run` function, you execute the graph. Tensors and Variables are assigned values in the graph, but the graph defines only the flow of computation, it does not hold any values. The real computation occurs when you run the session. One can create many session where each session can assign different values to the variable, that is why the graph has a `get_by_tensor_name` which outputs the tensor whose name is given as parameter.

You don't have the same mechanism in Js. You can use the variable as soon as you define them. It means that whenever you define a new tensor or variable, you can print it in the following line whereas in python, you can only print the tensor or variable only during a session. The `get_by_tensor_name` does not really have a sense in Js.

As for the predict function, you do have one in Js as well. if you create a model using `tf.model` or `tf.sequential`, you can invoke `predict` to make a prediction.

Comment: But i still don't no how to load a model and use tf.model to predict in tfjs even read the tfjs doc. Do you have an example about the syntax?  
I have a web format frozen model converted by tfjs converter. But how to load the converted frozen model and fit the input and get the four output.

Comment: You have this tutorial that will help you to load a frozen model https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-saved-model.html . In the Js API, you can get the output of a tensor just by calling the method `dataSync` or `data` on the sensor.