# Tensorflow.js SymbolicTensor not accepted as an input

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to reproduce the A2C algorithm in Tensorflow.js, and I think I have managed to successfully reproduce the models for the actor and the critic.

However, I am using a one hot encoding in order to provide my current state as an input to my model, and prior to that, I am setting up the input using the tf.input() function, which returns a SymbolicTensor (which for me, acts the same way as tf.placeholder in the Python API).

The tf.oneHot function only accepts tf.Tensor objects as first parameters, and I see no workaround in the documentation. I would have thought that the tf.SymbolicTensor is inherited from tf.Tensor, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

```
class A2CAgent {
    constructor(state_size, action_size) {
        this.render = false;
        this.state_size = state_size;
        this.action_size = action_size;
        this.value_size = 1;

        this.discount_factor = 0.99;
        this.actor_learningr = 0.001;
        this.critic_learningr = 0.005;

        this.actor = this.build_actor();
        #this.critic = this.build_critic();

    }

    build_actor() {
        const model = tf.sequential();

        this.state = tf.input({name:"state", dtype:'int32', shape:[]});
        let one_hot = tf.oneHot(this.state, this.state_size); //Pb ne prend pas de placeholder
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({
            units: 24,
            activation: 'relu',
            kernelInitializer:'glorotUniform',
            inputDim:tf.expandDims(one_hot, 0),
        }));

        model.add(tf.layers.dense({
            units: this.action_size,
            activation:'softmax',
            kernelInitializer:'glorotUniform',
        }));

        model.summary();

        model.compile({
            optimizer: tf.train.adam(this.actor_learningr),
            loss:tf.losses.softmaxCrossEntropy
        });

        return model;
    }
}
```

I would expect this code to execute just fine, but I get this error instead :

```
Error: Argument 'indices' passed to 'oneHot' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'SymbolicTensor'
```

Any idea on how to possibly fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

[tf.oneHot](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.2/#oneHot) takes several parameters but the 2 required `indices` and `depth` are respectively of type `tensor1d` and `number`.
To create a dense layer, you don't have to pass in a onehot encoding tensor especially when using a sequential model. You might have to supply a onehot tensor to the model, but it will happen only when you will fit your model with the features and label data during the training.

`tf.js` does not have a placeholder-like approach of tensorflow which first build a graph before executing it in a session. You may refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52623147/how-to-implement-get-tensor-by-name-and-predict-in-tensorflow-js) which highlights this difference between the two implementations

Also, notice that `inputDim` should be a number and not a tensor

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I could check it out earlier, and I noticed that I did things a bit too fast. I made the necessary changes to use oneHot encoding, but one question remains : what input dimensions should I use then ? The oneHot matrix's shape ?

Comment: @tarzan212 The dimensions to give are that of the input data. If the input of your model is the onehot vector, then use the property `inputShape` instead of `inputDim` and give to it as value the shape of the onehot vector. If the answer solves your issue do not forget to mark it as accepted :)